# iOS 5 upgrade changed font appearance

Tags: fonts, ios5, uitextfield

My app uses the "♥ BLACK HEART SUIT Unicode: U+2665, UTF-8: E2 99 A5" and "♡ WHITE HEART SUIT Unicode: U+2661, UTF-8: E2 99 A1" characters in UITextFields and in some UITableViewCell's titles.  Since upgrading target iPhone to iOS 5, the "white heart suit" still displays as expected BUT the "black heart suit" now displays as a graphic; a red heart on a white field.

This is unwelcome.

How can I get back to where I once belonged, that is, with the font simply displaying the character and not this graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue yet. In iOS 5 some of these special characters are rendered as emoji, and ♥ is one of them. Even explicitly setting font for your view doesn't help, but drawing characters directly with `draw...` methods seem to work (but not very useful always). It seems there's no way for disabling this at the moment. I hope an update will introduce a way to disable these.

Comment: Terrible news, but I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/a2-cocoaheads/browse_thread/thread/4c209e888cf2f702?pli=1), it appears that not all fonts are emoji-forced.  I don't have an exhaustive list, but the ArialMT family works fine for the characters in question; that is to say, the characters and not the emoji are displayed.  This will do for me until a real solution appears from Apple