# how to prevent iOS from converting ascii into emoji?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, emoji

I have this simple `String` applied to a `UILabel`

```
labelInfo.text = "(11) ♥ 6"
```

this is how I need it to look like

> (11) ♥ 6

this is how it looks like instead

> [image: unwanted]

I really searched **alot**, and didn't find a way to do this..

I found ways to remove emojis, but this makes it look like this

> (11)  6

if you have a hint, it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple has changed this in iOS 5. In most fonts, all characters that can be potentially displayed as an emoji are replaced with the colorful character from the Apple Emoji Font.

There are several solutions:

1. Use the Unicode variant selector for *non-coloured glyph*: U+FE0E

`labelInfo.text = "(11) \u{2665}\u{fe0e} 6"`

2. Set a font where Apple doesn't force emojis. People usually recommend *Hiragino Mincho ProN*.
3. Use the graphics contexts drawing method to display the text.

Also see:

- [Unicode characters being drawn differently in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335724/unicode-characters-being-drawn-differently-in-ios5/8412044#8412044)
- [Prevent Emoji Characters from Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208126/prevent-emoji-characters-from-showing)
- [iOS 5 upgrade changed font appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318135/ios-5-upgrade-changed-font-appearance)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit->Emoji and Symbols in Xcode.Type the name of symbol you want to use(in your case heart).Copy it.Then paste it the way you want.    Eg:_mylabel.text=@"♥︎";
[image: Example]

Comment: that's a good answer, but we still don't get all symbols as some will be reserved for emojis ? or i'm mistaken ?

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me:**

Please make sure to use the actual ASCII symbol instead of code and append `\u{0000FE0E}` after it like shown below:

`label.text = "♥\u{0000FE0E} Love!"`

It will show up in label correctly like this:

`♥ Love!`

**Note**: Please make sure that the symbol exists in your font. In case it does not work, please try changing the font. Thank you.